# Is there a way to run Qt Creator from command line supplying a .pro file to open (or how do we deal with multiple Qt installations)?

Tags: qt, qt4, version, qt-creator, projects-and-solutions

I have multiple installations of Qt4 on my Windows XP SP2 machine and have installed Qt Creator 2.1 today. However, running the project (`.pro`) files spawns the *oldest* version of Qt Designer installed (the one installed in 2009 together with the rest of the framework).

Since

- I would not like to remove any previous installations of Qt
- and for some obscure reason even if I explicitly ask Windows Explorer to always use the version I need it does not

I would like to give up a bit and just sript the needed behaviour in a `.bat` file like:

```
e:\path\to\qtcreator.exe %1
```

This opens Qt Creator, but something seems to prevent it from treating the .pro file properly (in short, the project does not "open" as it should).

Qt documents have a page on the matter at [Qt Creator: Using Command Line Options](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-cli.html), but it seems to ignore the topic in question.

Since Qt (being as excellent framework as it is) is also known to have its quirks (like that of `qmake`), I wonder, may be there is an undocumented way to solve my problem?

*(Another way to fix the thing would of course be to make the correct version of Qt Designer run, but frankly I'd prefer the "hard-wired" solution since the mechanisms provided by Qt itself are still a bit unreliable.)*

Answer (score 1):

The libraries and tools used for a particular project (and a configuration in it) is set in the Projects panel in Qt Creator:
http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html

Selecting the Qt version to use with a project should force it to run the Designer that's part of the version. If it doesn't, then you should report it as a bug.